# Aggregating in R conditional on the date

Tags: r, time

I have some data, where I aggregate the information on a unique minute basis with the below code based on a dataset for 1 day. 
I would however like to be able to run this code with a datafile that is combined of multiple days. I have a date column in the dataset, so I can use that as a unique identifier for each day. Is there a way to aggregate the data on a 1 minute basis, given that the dates aren't the same?

The problem is that the unique function extracts the unique events that occur the first day, and then adds all the same events that happen in that minute afterwards. If i base it on the date too, I believe I can create unique 1-minute entries for each day in one long dataset.

Below is the code that works for a single days data.

```
novo <- read.csv("C:/Users/Morten/Desktop/data.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE  )

TimeStamp <- novo[,1]
price <- novo[, 2]
volume <- novo[,3]
nV <- sum(volume) 

MinutesFloor <- unique(floor(TimeStamp))
nTradingMinutes <- length(MinutesFloor)

PriceMin <- rep(0, nTradingMinutes)
VolumeMin <- rep(0, nTradingMinutes)

for( j in 1:nTradingMinutes){
    ThisMinutes <- (floor(TimeStamp) == MinutesFloor[j])
    PriceMin[j] <- mean(price[ThisMinutes])
    VolumeMin[j] <- sum(volume[ThisMinutes])

    }
```

Thanks in advance

data format:

date,"ord","shares","finalprice","time","stock"
20100301,C,80,389,540.004,1158
20100301,C,77,389,540.004,1158
20100301,C,60,389,540.004,1158
20100301,C,28,389,540.004,1158
20100301,C,7,389,540.004,1158
20100302,C,25,394.7,540.00293333,1158
20100302,C,170,394.7,540.00293333,1158
20100302,C,40,394.7,540.00293333,1158
20100302,C,75,394.7,540.00293333,1158
20100302,C,100,394.7,540.00293333,1158
20100302,C,1,394.7,540.00293333,1158

Comment: Please provide a few rows of your dataset. try ?head

Comment: I added a piece of the dataset in the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest a radically simplified version of your code.

You are doing quite a few things rather inefficient. R is made to compute summary statistics clustered by different data values. 
We will use this methods heavily.

I assume your data to be of the form you provided. At my system, this looks like

```
novo <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE  )
```

This gives us:

```
> str(novo)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ date      : int  20100301 20100301 20100301 20100301 20100301 20100302 20100302 20100302 20100302 20100302 ...
 $ ord       : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ shares    : int  80 77 60 28 7 25 170 40 75 100 ...
 $ finalprice: num  389 389 389 389 389 ...
 $ time      : num  540 540 540 540 540 ...
 $ stock     : int  1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 1158 ...
```

Now, I assume that your date is ordered YearMonthDate. If you have a different ordering, you would have to alter the format command below. Furthermore, your `time` probably is in minutes.

Then we can create timestamps containing both the date and the time using the `POSIXct` datatype:

```
timestamps <- as.POSIXct(as.character(novo$date), format='%Y%m%d') + novo$time*60
```

Now, we do the rounding up minutes by creating a factor variable and using the `cut` function:

```
timestampsByMinute <- droplevels(cut(timestamps, 'min'))
```

Note that the additional `droplevels` function just removes the minutes that have no data item s available.

Finally, we may compute the summary statistics you did in the `for`-loop:

`tapply` is a function taking it's first argument, dividing it into groups defined by the second argument and applying the function given as third argument to that data. Thus we may just throw the `tapply` function on your data. (I have the feeling that the column numbers you used in your code do not match the column names in your example data - feel free to adapt to different columns if I interpreted your meaning the wrong way)

```
PriceMin <-  tapply(novo$finalprice, timestampsByMinute, mean)
VolumeMin <- tapply(novo$shares, timestampsByMinute, sum)
```

This gives us

```
> PriceMin
2010-03-01 09:00:00 2010-03-02 09:00:00 
              389.0               394.7 
> VolumeMin
2010-03-01 09:00:00 2010-03-02 09:00:00 
                252                 411
```

which is probably what you want.

Note that `tapply` is much faster that the loop you used. If you have huge datafiles, this may be important.

I hope there are no errors left in my code - testing was not easy given the fact that you provided only data for one minute per day.

---

Edit:

As per request, here a small modification that removes the time information from the data:

```
> unname(VolumeMin)
[1] 252 411

> unname(PriceMin)
[1] 389.0 394.7
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. When trying to run this I get an error at the timestampsByMinute <- droplevels(cut(date, 'min')) function. I get the error that date is not numerical. It is stated to be an integer as well for me at at the beginning str(novo) . Did you change the class of the vector, or is there something that I am overlooking?

Comment: @user1554592 Ah, foolish me... `dates` should of course be `Timestamps`. I corrected my answer above.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I however need the VolumeMin and PriceMin to be independent vectors, and not have the time and date in the same column in the array. I use VolumeMin and PriceMin in a algorithm after this aggregation, so they need to be seperated from the date and time stamp. 
I tried altering tapply so simplify = FALSE, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: @user1554592 The date- and timestamps are vectors that have named elements. They can be used as if they had no time information attached to them. Note that you will never get them independent of the time they were collected at in a statistical sense. You only can throw the information away and suggest some kind of independence. If that is really what you want, you always can do `unname(VolumeMin)` and `unname(PriceMin)`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a vector of length(VolumeMin) and simply have the produced sum per minute in each row? With each row representing an added minute?

Comment: @user1554592: That is exactly what should happen if you use `unname(VolumeMin)`. Note, however, that this vector will not contain minutes where no data has been available. Depending on your data that could or could not be a problem.

Comment: That is exactly what my previous output produced too. The problem is that the format of the unname(VolumeMin) variable is an array, that looks like 
[[1]]
[1] 28249

[[2]]
[1] 3453

[[3]]
[1] 5301

[[4]]
[1] 1051

[[5]]
[1] 4318 
 - formatting is not correct here. But in order to read it in it has to be arranged as a normal vector like [1] 28249 3453 ... etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19947/discussion-between-thilo-and-user1554592)